# Function handle to a built-in operator in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given the following minimal snippet of code:

```
def cmp(a, b, cmp):
    return cmp(a, b)

a = 1
b = 2
print(cmp(a, b, operator.__eq__))
```

I'd just like to give a built-in operator like `==` or `>` as a function handle into a function. This would be useful for example, if comparisons **all** need some pre-checks.

**The last line gives an error, as it does not know `operator.__eq__`. How do I correctly name (and import) that `==` operator on that line?**

Comment: `import operator`?

Comment: `import operator` and `operator.eq`?

Comment: Thanks, that works! I fooled around with things like `from operator import __eq__`. I do not exactly understand, why I can not do that?

Comment: @Michael because it's not called `__eq__` but `eq`! I'm guessing the `__eq__` object is actually the module's equality operator (e.g. to test if `operator == my_module`).

Comment: @acdr `__eq__` should be in `operator`, too. At least it is in my Python 3.4.3

Comment: both `__eq__` and `eq` are in the `operator` module. `__eq__` is the magic method, `eq` is one of the "non-magic" methods of this particular module because it's the `operator` module. @Michael use `operator.eq` if you can; `__eq__` determines what `==` means as (at)acdr mentioned. Magic methods (double underscores) allow you to re-define the language on a more fundamental level. Eg. `class int(int): def __add__(self,a): print("your mom!")` would give some funky results when you later cast something to `int()` and try to do an addtion. E.g. `[int(x) + int(x) for x in "1 2 3". split()]`

Comment: @jDo I have a different understanding of the doc (`eq` being only a copy of `__eq__` for convenience  and in fact `operator.__eq__ is operator.eq` evaluates to `True` here).

Comment: @mkiever Your example is certainly correct - I just wonder what it means. As I understand it, methods prefixed and suffixed by two underscores signify [magic methods](http://rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html) but `operator` must be different then. E.g. in py3.4 `type(int.__add__)` shows `<class 'wrapper_descriptor'>` (same for most (all?) built-in types) but `type(operator.__add__)` shows `<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>`. Maybe underscore methods for `operator` shouldn't be called magic methods at all if they're just mnemonics/aliases for built-ins; I don't know.

Comment: @jDo Yes, module `operator` seems to contain the base magic operators, not yet restricted to a specific operand type. They are somehow made "unmagic".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `import operator` and the code is working.

```
import operator

def cmp(a, b, _cmp):
    return _cmp(a, b)

a = 1
b = 2
print(cmp(a, b, operator.__eq__))
```

I have renamed the function parameter for clarity.